# Indian restaurant in Montevideo

Tags: restaurants, uruguay, montevideo

I have a friend who will be visiting Montevideo, Uruguay next month.  Her stay in Montevideo would be anything between 6-12 months.  She is a pure vegetarian and is extremely concerned with the food arrangements there.

Can anyone suggest a good Indian restaurant/food stalls selling Indian cuisine. I googled out but could not find any appropriate result.  Maybe someone already residing there can really help.

Comment: I couldn't find any Indian restaurant, but maybe [this](http://www.happycow.net/reviews/namaste-montevideo-16363) could be an option. It says they don't use onion or garlic or eggs, and if you read the comments there seem to be vegan options available.

Answer (score 4):

After some searching, there's a restaurant called Tandory, at 
Ramon Masini esq. Libertad, Montevideo 11300, Uruguay (Pocitos).

Here's the [official website](http://www.tandory.com.uy/), with their [menu (in Spanish)](http://www.tandory.com.uy/menuacute.html).

The [reviews on TripAdvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Restaurant_Review-g294323-d1102759-Reviews-Tandory-Montevideo_Montevideo_Department.html) sound amazing.

I had concerns about whether or not it was vegetarian, however - they have some options, and it'll depend on how vegetarian or fussy your friend is, I guess.  Take a look at the menu, and if it's not suitable (eg they have salads, citrus risotto, vegetarian samosas..) then let us know.

([English translation of menu through Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=es&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http://www.tandory.com.uy/menuacute.html&act=url))

Comment: Tandory is not an indian restaurant as the name suggests, however, it may be the
closest thing you will find in Montevideo. The food is good, keeping in mind it's a hybrid of Indian cuisine and a combination of several others. For starters you may want to try the samosas but please stay away from the falafels as they are hard and dry with no flavor. For the main course we had curry langostinos (shrimp), which was quite
good. We felt that it could have been even better without the peanuts and grapes. The 'Sole in the Cafe de Paris' was also good, very nicely done. For dessert you should try the

Comment: @Sube' try the what? the what? Don't leave us hanging for months ;)

Answer (score 3):

I was in Uruguay for about a year we don't have any Indian restaurants. The closest thing would be Chinese fried rice in Jaun bonito blank st (I don't remember the exact location).

But you also have good Indian food in Argentina 3-4 hrs from port of Montevideo. Delhi taj and bombay. We also don't get any Indian grocery there. All Indians stock kilograms of Indian masala from home and the kitchen is no less than an Indian grocery shop.