# Is there an Indian food market in Montevideo?

Tags: indian-citizens, food-and-drink, uruguay, montevideo

I will be travelling to Uruguay with my family in couple of months. I am pure vegetarian and wanted to find an Indian supermarket where we can get Indian products so that we can bring only necessary items which are not available.

I tried to search in Google, but didn't get any info. If you can share some info or URL or photos would be good.

Comment: Thanks for the details.. so I understood that there is no direct indian food product available in Uruguay.. Raw material we can find in local market and have to built our food production accordingly.. such as Ghee from Butter, spices from raw items, etc..  Also could you please help me what items are easily available in Uruguay? Ex Rice, daals, wheat flour, etc

Answer (score 1):

I do not know whether there is an Indian food market in Montevideo, but I know that all the basic food stuff are sold in the city.
And not just the basics, also some of the spices and special items you are used to at home.

You might need to look for the translation of the names of things, but almost all will be for sale, in markets or in small shops or even in supermarkets where the locals do their shopping. And you may need to learn to adjust or make some of the items, like using oil instead of ghee or making your own ghee from butter.

In this [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25389/indian-restaurant-in-montevideo) people answered that Indian people 
bring rice from home, but if you are willing to use different rice, you can buy locally.

If you decide to bring food from home, be aware that importing food and seeds is often not allowed into countries. And when you may import, it has to be free from diseases (and often you need a certificate to prove that.)

Comment: With all due respect, this answer seems a bit flippant: there are plenty of things needed for Indian cuisine (eg. ghee) that are not a part of the Uruguayan diet and will not be found in your average local supermarket under any name.

Comment: You can make your own ghee from butter, which will be available. There are many work around methods, and the basic food stuffs are the same in both areas.

Comment: This related question disagrees with you: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25389/indian-restaurant-in-montevideo